# SQL - Update Multiple Tables, Where Inner Join Value is from Third Table

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL Database I have tables labeled as the following:

```
Table:catalog_product_entity
|-------------------------|
|entity_id | sku          |  
|-------------------------|
|5         | 094922562333 |
|6         | 087454664234 |
|7         | 054545789548 |
---------------------------

Table:catalog_product_entity_decimal
|-------------------------|
|entity_id | price        |  
|-------------------------|
|5         | 39.99        |
|6         | 37.92        |
|7         | 5.99         |
---------------------------

Table: cataloginventory_stock_item
|-------------------------|
|entity_id | qty          |  
|-------------------------|
|5         | 0            |
|6         | 5            |
|7         | 8            |
---------------------------
```

I'm connecting to another database that can only provide me the SKU. I'm wanting to use the SKU as a INNER JOIN to update the tables using the entity_id with one query.

Here is the query I have so far (getting syntax error):

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal, cataloginventory_stock_item
SET catalog_product_entity_decimal.value ='37.95',                                                          
cataloginventory_stock_item.qty ='4'
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity 
ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id
WHERE catalog_product_entity.sku = '094922562333';
```

Comment: I updated my question. MySQL - Thank you.

Comment: I think you need two update queries. Columns from two different table are present in `SET`

Comment: @Prdp Yes, I know the easy and lazy way would be two queries but for optimization and speed - I would like one query.

Comment: That looks like magento ;). Can you please shpw is the syntax error you get. And please try to rephrase it as a select and run it. That normaly helps.

Comment: In the context of what you've presented, it's not clear to me what you mean by _"Inner Join Value is from Third Table"_. You can't use a table to join two other tables without joining that table to **both** of those tables; in what you've provided, there is nothing saying which records of `cataloginventory_stock_item` should be included, so ALL records from that table will end up updated.

Comment: _Also, while it is often the case, it is best not to assume that a single, joined query will always be better for optimization and speed than multiple simpler ones; especially when the tables involved are not linking easily to begin with._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JOIN` is part of the `UPDATE` statement, not after the `SET`.  So you might try:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal cped JOIN
       catalog_product_entity cpe
       ON cpe.entity_id = cped.entity_id JOIN
       cataloginventory_stock_item csi
       ON csi.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
    SET cped.value = 37.95,                                                          
        csi.qty = 4
    WHERE cpe.sku = '094922562333';
```

Notes:

- The `JOIN`s are in the `UPDATE` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You need a `JOIN` for `cataloginventory_stock_item`.
- Single quotes are not required around numbers.